examples of technological milestones that have impacted mathematics education
I am trying to create a timeline of technological revolutions and their impacts on mathematics education. The advent of pocket calculators and artificial intelligence are two examples of these technological milestones that have impacted mathematics education. The invention of the decimal number system is possibly another example. My question: are there other relevant milestones?

Perhaps include https://hsm.stackexchange.com/q/12945/229 "Blackboards as Math Tech"

This certainly depends on the resolution one is using while looking at history. So some suggestions at different levels of resolution.

language
printing press and further developments in book production technology
stick on sand, clay writing tablet, cheap paper, modern pencils and pens, blackboard, whiteboard, (overhead) projector, smartboard
computers and their advancement, like the increasingly graphical user interfaces and computing power
spreadsheets
Geogebra
CAS
programming and advancements in it, including block programming
internet, including forums, Q&A sites, scientific journal websites, Scihub, etc.

The question is quite broad. I think it would be a good idea to restrict the question a bit more.

I'm not sure that I would call decimals a technology.  But if you are including ways of writing math, than I think the advent of writing symbolic algebra around the time of Descartes in the 1600s*, was a major step forward.  It is just so much easier to manipulate algebra equations than text strings.
*It's an approximation.  Some notation was developed before, some after.  But certainly by 1700, we have very recognizable lines of equations as the complete norm.  And in 1500, we had text strings in Latin as the norm.
